# How to iteratively run a program on multi-resolution files?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, if-statement, iterator

`.mcool` files contain matrices for multiple resolutions.

For every file in `./input/*.mcool`, if `cooler ls "$mcool_file"` ends with `5000`, `10000`, or `50000` after the last `/`, I want to run `predictSV` from [EagleC](https://github.com/XiaoTaoWang/EagleC).

As shown on the repo, a single `.mcool` file

```
predictSV --hic-5k SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool::/resolutions/5000 \
          --hic-10k SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool::/resolutions/10000 \
          --hic-50k SKNAS-MboI-allReps-filtered.mcool::/resolutions/50000 \
          -O SK-N-AS -g hg38 --balance-type CNV --output-format full \
          --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999
```

However, for a list of files, I need to write a for-loop to iteratively run `predictSV`.

Attempt 1:

```
for mcool_file in ./input/*.mcool; do
  while IFS= read -r id; do
    id_suffix=${id##*/}
    case $id_suffix in 5000|10000|50000)
      num=${id_suffix:0:1}
      predictSV \
        --hic-"${num}k" "$id_suffix" \
        -g hg38 \
        -O basename "${id%%.*}" \
        --balance-type CNV \
        --output-format full \
        --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 \
        --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 \
        --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999
      ;;
    esac
  done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")
done
```

Traceback:

```
usage: predictSV [-h] [-v] [--hic-5k HIC_5K] [--hic-10k HIC_10K]
                 [--hic-50k HIC_50K] [-O OUTPUT_PREFIX]
                 [-g {hg38,hg19,chm13,other}] [-C [CHROMS ...]]
                 [--balance-type {ICE,CNV,Raw}]
                 [--output-format {full,NeoLoopFinder}]
                 [--prob-cutoff-5k PROB_CUTOFF_5K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-10k PROB_CUTOFF_10K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-50k PROB_CUTOFF_50K]
predictSV: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: predictSV [-h] [-v] [--hic-5k HIC_5K] [--hic-10k HIC_10K]
                 [--hic-50k HIC_50K] [-O OUTPUT_PREFIX]
                 [-g {hg38,hg19,chm13,other}] [-C [CHROMS ...]]
                 [--balance-type {ICE,CNV,Raw}]
                 [--output-format {full,NeoLoopFinder}]
                 [--prob-cutoff-5k PROB_CUTOFF_5K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-10k PROB_CUTOFF_10K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-50k PROB_CUTOFF_50K]
predictSV: error: unrecognized arguments: --hic-1k 10000
usage: predictSV [-h] [-v] [--hic-5k HIC_5K] [--hic-10k HIC_10K]
                 [--hic-50k HIC_50K] [-O OUTPUT_PREFIX]
                 [-g {hg38,hg19,chm13,other}] [-C [CHROMS ...]]
                 [--balance-type {ICE,CNV,Raw}]
                 [--output-format {full,NeoLoopFinder}]
                 [--prob-cutoff-5k PROB_CUTOFF_5K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-10k PROB_CUTOFF_10K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-50k PROB_CUTOFF_50K]
predictSV: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: predictSV [-h] [-v] [--hic-5k HIC_5K] [--hic-10k HIC_10K]
                 [--hic-50k HIC_50K] [-O OUTPUT_PREFIX]
                 [-g {hg38,hg19,chm13,other}] [-C [CHROMS ...]]
                 [--balance-type {ICE,CNV,Raw}]
                 [--output-format {full,NeoLoopFinder}]
                 [--prob-cutoff-5k PROB_CUTOFF_5K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-10k PROB_CUTOFF_10K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-50k PROB_CUTOFF_50K]
predictSV: error: unrecognized arguments:
usage: predictSV [-h] [-v] [--hic-5k HIC_5K] [--hic-10k HIC_10K]
                 [--hic-50k HIC_50K] [-O OUTPUT_PREFIX]
                 [-g {hg38,hg19,chm13,other}] [-C [CHROMS ...]]
                 [--balance-type {ICE,CNV,Raw}]
                 [--output-format {full,NeoLoopFinder}]
                 [--prob-cutoff-5k PROB_CUTOFF_5K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-10k PROB_CUTOFF_10K]
                 [--prob-cutoff-50k PROB_CUTOFF_50K]
..
```

Attempt 2:

```
for mcool_file in ./input/*.mcool; do
  while IFS= read -r id; do
    id_suffix=${id##*/}
    case $id_suffix in 5000|10000|50000)
      num=${id_suffix:0:1}
      predictSV \
        if [ $id_suffix=5000 ];
          then --hic-5k "$id_suffix";
        elif [ $id_suffix=10000 ];
          then --hic-10k "$id_suffix";
        else:
          --hic-50k "$id_suffix";
        fi \
        -g hg38 \
        -O basename "${id%%.*}" \
        --balance-type CNV \
        --output-format full \
        --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 \
        --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 \
        --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999
      ;;
    esac
  done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")
done
```

Cooler for one `.mcool` file:

```
cooler ls ./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool

./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/200
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/500
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/1000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/2000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/5000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/10000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/20000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/50000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/100000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/250000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/500000
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/1000000
(EagleC)
```

Comment: Start with the common pitfalls, files  has windows line endings? Does `predictSV` consumes `STDIN`?

Comment: Also Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: You should provide the output of `cooler ls somefile.mcool` and what command you want to run for it

Comment: @Fravadona Added the output for `for id in cooler ls ./input/*.mcool; do echo "$id"; done`

Comment: @melolili The output of `cooler ls ./input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool` would be more useful

Comment: The usage says `--hic-1k` isn't supported; it only specifies `5k`, `10k` and `50k` as permitted.

Comment: And no, you can't embed an `if` in a command line. We have other already-answered Q&A telling you that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not aiming for `--hic-1k`. I'm attempting to retrieve files with `5000`, `10000`, and `50000` substring using `case $id_suffix in 5000|10000|50000)`. Then, remove the last three zeros and append a `k`, such that 5000 is 5k, 10000 is 10k, and 50000 is 50k.

Comment: One question you still haven't answered: If the output from a file has all three of 5k, 10k and 50k resolutions, do you run `predictSV` one time with three arguments, or three separate times with one argument each?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy one time with three arguments, as shown in the `predictSV` example in the repo.

Comment: We don't follow links to 3rd-party repositories here. Questions that require people to do so are incomplete and thus wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added that part of the `predictSV` repo in my question.

Comment: BTW, in `-O basename "${id%%.*}"`, remember, only the _last_ id is still populated when the loop finishes. What do you expect that to _actually_ do?

Comment: The `-O basename "${id%%.*}"` instructs that if the input file is `*A001C007*` append `A001C007` to all the relevant output files, such that the output files are `A001C007.CNN_SVs.10K_highres.txt`, `A001C007.CNN_SVs.10K.txt`, `A001C007.CNN_SVs.50K_highres.txt`, `A001C007.CNN_SVs.50K.txt`, `A001C007.CNN_SVs.5K_combined.txt`, and `A001C007.CNN_SVs.5K.txt`

Comment: ...why... would the code do that?

Comment: The `-O` parameter is for specifying the prefix for the output file. I can call it anything I want and chose to add that substring.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking why the code _you wrote_ would do that. You're passing the literal string `basename`, not the output of the command named `basename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been nice if, in the prior question, you had described what you were trying to do well enough to allow a correct answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for mcool_file in input/*.mcool; do

  # iterate over ids emitted from cooler ls for this file
  hic5k_num=; hic10k_num=; hic50k_num=
  while IFS= read -r id; do
    id_suffix=${id##*/}
    case $id_suffix in
      5000)  hic5k_num=$id_suffix;;
      10000) hic10k_num=$id_suffix;;
      50000) hic50k_num=$id_suffix;;
    esac
  done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")

  predictSV \
   ${hic5k_num:+  --hic-5k "$hic5k_num"} \
   ${hic10k_num:+ --hic-10k "$hic10k_num"} \
   ${hic50k_num:+ --hic-50k "$hic50k_num"} \
   -g hg38 \
   -O "${mcool_file%%.*}" \
   --balance-type CNV \
   --output-format full \
   --prob-cutoff-5k 0.8 \
   --prob-cutoff-10k 0.8 \
   --prob-cutoff-50k 0.99999
done
```