# Is not an HDF5 file error when iterating over multi-resolution HDF5 files

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, hdf5, hdf

I want to run `cooler balance` (from [cooler](https://cooler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#cooler-balance)) on each resolution of each file with `.mcool` extension.

```
 for mcool_file in input/*.mcool; do
  while IFS= read -r id; do # id=./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/200   
    cooler balance ${id}
  done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")

done
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.local/bin/cooler", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cooler/cli/fileops.py", line 24, in ls
    for group_path in fileops.list_coolers(cool_path):
  File "/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cooler/fileops.py", line 186, in list_coolers
    raise OSError(f"'{filepath}' is not an HDF5 file.")
OSError: 'input/*.mcool' is not an HDF5 file.
```

The following Python code did not raise an error, suggesting that the `.mcool` files are in valid `hdf5` format.

```
import h5py
if not h5py.is_hdf5('A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool'):
    raise ValueError('Not an hdf5 file')
```

List of resolution for a .mcool file (e.g., A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool) can be identified using:

```
cooler ls A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
```

which returns:

```
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/200
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/500
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/1000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/2000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/5000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/10000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/20000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/50000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/100000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/250000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/500000
A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool::/resolutions/1000000
```

For a single resolution of a single file, it can be run as:

`cooler balance [OPTIONS] COOL_PATH`

Comment: `cooler balance ${id%%.*};` is outside of the loop. The loop ends when `read -r id` fails, and this sets `$id` to an empty string.

Comment: It's not clear what your intention is. If you want to use the last id of the loop, assign it to another variable.

Comment: And if you want to process every id, move that line inside the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, I intend to run `cooler balance [OPTIONS] COOL_PATH` on each resolution in each file

Comment: Then move that line up, before the `done < <(cooler ls "$mcool_file")` line

Comment: The code in the question, as-edited, has no `esac` -- the error messages don't line up with the code that purportedly caused them. Consider using http://shellcheck.net/ to check for syntax errors, btw -- and be sure that when you update your code, you update your errors/output too.

Comment: Sorry updated the question

Comment: Are you running this in a directory relative to which any files matching `input/*.mcool` actually exist? By default, when no files match a glob, that glob expression expands to itself.

Comment: To be clear, the error isn't telling you that the files are in the wrong format. Instead, it's telling you that no file named `*.mcool` exists -- that is, it's telling you that the glob expression isn't being successfully replaced by a list of matching filenames before your Python code tries to open it.